# Nginx user gets "permission denied" on stat command instead of "no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, nginx, drupal

The Nginx error log is filling up with failures of the "stat" command, executed by Nginx, with "permission denied" errors. When executing the stat command on a none existing file or folder, I would expect to get a "No such file or directory" error.

The weird thing is when I run the stat command on the server with the Nginx user, I get the "permission denied" error again. If I run the same command as root, I get the "No such file or directory" error. After I ran the command as root and rerun it as the Nginx user, I suddenly get the "No such file or directory".

Another weird thing, this behavior only happens in the "web" directory of a Drupal project. Trying the same command in other directories doesn't seem to give the same "permission denied" error.

Trying to search on this issue only results in permission settings issues with Nginx, but the fact that the command works after running it as root seems to indicate there is another issue here.

I don't think it would matter for this issue. But the application does run in a container, but there is no volume mount in that directory. When running a new container from the image, I do not get these same "Permission Denied" error but the expected "No such file or directory". Maybe it is something that happens over time?

Any help would be appreciated, cause I'm kinda out of ideas.

Comment: It may be SELinux denying access to the command or directory before the `stat` command actually executes. Reset the labels. If that does not fix it, then inspect the SELinux contexts. Folks at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) can help with the SELinux issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response @jww. Unfortunately, SELinux is not enabled on the server. So this will not be the problem.